# KPI's for Webmasters

Tags: performance

Do you know any Key Performance Indicators for Webmasters? What should be measured and monitored?

Comment: What are you paying your webmaster to do? (As discussed here on meta, it's a pretty broad term and encompasses a wide range of skillsets)

Comment: You can be more specific when asking something like that. As pointed by @danlefree, "webmaster" covers a lot of different skills and usually depends on interpretation from QA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they designed it:

- Bounce rate
- Visit duration
- Conversion rate

If they coded it:

- Page load time
- Code validity (via validator tools)
- Page accessibility (via audit)

If they manage it:

- Uptime (measure with [Pingdom](http://pingdom.com) or similar)
- Server load
- Worldwide response times
- Time taken to resolve tickets
- Time taken to restore from backup
- Critical errors (via server logs)

If they promote it:

- Unique visits
- Repeat visits
- Size of email lists
- Size of RSS subscriber lists

If they write the content:

- Number of social 'shares'
- Number of inbound links
- Page views

If it's a web app or paid service:

- Churn rate
- Cost of acquisition
- Average income per customer
- Turnover

Answer (score 0):

I feel, you can consider the following points

1. Make sure there are no Errors in google webmasters login for the website
2. No Broken links
3. How many page views(this will be a bench mark for any webmaster)

Comment: 1 & 2 are not really KPIs (although I guess it depends on what you define as 'performance') and 3 may not be a 'webmasters' responsibility (whatever webmaster means).